# Обработка нажатия на часть родительского элемента, на которой нет дочерних блоков

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть два блока: div1 и div2. Первый является родительским элементом второго. Как обработать нажатие на часть div1, на которой не находится div2. Желательно с использованием средств jQuery, но можно и на чистом JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

parent.addEventListener( 'click', e => {
  if( e.target !== parent ) return;
  console.log('clicked on parent');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

На jQuery:

```js
let parent = $('.parent');

parent.on( 'click', e => {
  if( e.target !== parent[0] ) return;
  console.log('clicked on parent');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Если отдельная переменная родителя мешает, то можно делать так:

```
$('.parent').on( 'click', function(e){ // заменено на обычную функцию
  if( e.target !== this ) return; // заменено на this
  console.log('clicked on parent');
});
```

Comment: `.on('click', ...)` => `.click(...)`. зы: можно еще запретить всплытие у внутреннего дива

Comment: @teran насчёт клика и прочих коротких методов видел неоднократно что они deprecated. На самом сайте jquery этого не написано, но встречалось раньше часто, даже в типах typescript вроде (могу ошибаться). Вот например https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnclick-event-shorthand-is-deprecated . А всплытие запрещать чревато, потом "более глобальные" слушатели могут неверно работать.